# How to make React app scroll to a specific element on a newly rendered page?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, rendering

I am struggling to find information about **how to make React app scroll to a specific element on a newly rendered page after clicking a corresponding element**. I have a homepage with 6 service cards. I also have a services page that includes more detailed descriptions about each service. I want the browser to automatically scroll to a corresponding service in the services page after a card in homepage was clicked.

**Here is the Card component in the homepage:**

```js
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    return (
        <div id={data.id} className="serviceCard slideUpContainer" onClick={() => navigate(data.link)}>
            <img src={require('../visuals/' + data.img + '.png')} alt={data.title} />
            <div className="slideUpContent">
                <h2 className="slideUpTitle">{data.title}</h2>
                <p className="slideUpText">{data.excerpt}</p>
                <div className="linkContainer">
                    <a href={data.link}>{data.btn}<i className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ServiceCard
```

**And here is the Service component in the services page:**

```js
    return (
        <div id={data.id} className={data.className}>
        <div id="imgBox">
            <img src={require('../visuals/services/' + data.blockImg + '.png')}
            alt={data.alt} />
        </div>
        <div id="textBox">
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
            <p>{data.description}</p>
            <div>
                <h3>{data.listName}</h3>
                <ul>
                    {data.listItems.map(item => 
                        <ServiceListItem key={nanoid()} data={item} />
                        )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

For now I was using `navigate()`, I also tried adding `/#ElementID` to the url and neither of those gives me the desired result. I was trying to find more info on the internet, but all I get is the scrolling option on the same page (which is easy).

Comment: Are you using Node JS or Deno?

Comment: Hello, @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, I am using NodeJs.

Comment: Just curious to know if `src={require('../visuals/services/' + data.blockImg + '.png')` really works?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yes! I`ve tried multimple solutions for images and this one proved to be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly rendered page means that you can use an empty dependencies 'useEffect' as a callback for when the component you want into view finishes rendering and is available in the DOM:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("ElementID").scrollIntoView();
    // or, use a ref and
    elementRef.current.scrollIntoView()
}, [])
```

You can also use on any parent component of the component you want into view, as parent's 'onEffect' is always called after a child has completely rendered (and its own 'onEffect' has already ran).

To complement this, you can also use in your CSS:

- [scroll-padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top) - if you have a sticky header or somehow the scroll doesn't center the element correctly
- [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) - for smooth scrolling, if you want this feature. If you want your page to instant scroll to this component, but have smooth scroll for everything else, you can also: disable smooth scroll -> scrollIntoView() -> re-enable smooth scroll.

Comment: Thank you! I applied the useEffect for the parent component of the services block and passed the elementID value via the props.